# Window caption is grey when hitting cancel from CFileDialog - why?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cfiledialog

It has been brought to my attention that `CFileDialog` has some odd behaviour. I am using it with a `CDialogEx` but I also tried with `CDialog`.

For example:

```
CFileDialog dlgSave(FALSE, _T(".SRR"),
    m_strFileName, OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, _T("*.SRR|*.SRR||"), this);
if (dlgSave.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
}
```

- Run that in a dialog project via a button.
- On the file dialog hit cancel

Now the title bar of the application dialog is greyed. Why? I can repeat this for any of my dialogs. But if I close with OK I don't get this issue.

[image]

Comment: I can't repro this, maybe its down to how you are calling this code? I use the exact same code as you've shown, and call it inside a method like this `void CmyMainDlg::OnFileSaveAs() { // CODE HERE };`

Comment: @user20716902 I create empty dialog app. Add a button. Call the code (basically like I have). Hit cancel on File dialog. Window caption remains grey. This is new install of WIndows 11 and another user reports same issue.

Comment: Interesting! I've just managed to reproduce this on a new dialog project. But it works on my existing apps.

Comment: @user20716902 Yeah, and it wll grey out a menu bar too if you have one on your dialog (even though you can click the menu items). Display a message box with `AfxMessageBox` and it returns to normal.

Comment: @user20716902 Are your existing apps dialog projects? Or SDI / MDI?

Comment: My apps are MFC dialogs, I'm comparing the newly created project with my existing app trying to identify the difference.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue with an empty MFC single dialog test app created by the wizard, when I changed all instances from CDialogEx to CDialog the issue is resolved.

Comment: @user20716902 I confirm that using `CDialog` does stop this behaviour. So there is a specific issue with using `CDialogEx` class.

Comment: This seems to have been a MS bug for a while, found this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/mfc-dialog-based-application-with-cdialogex/409317 But unfortunately MS closed it.

Comment: If you want to use CDialogEx, you can fix the problem by adding `FlashWindow(TRUE);` after the DoModal finishes.

Comment: @ user20716902 Or maybe derive my own class as mentioned in the linked Visual Studio ticket. @barmak-shemirani

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Dialog-based-application-with-CDialogEx/10518087

Comment: While we cannot vote on closed "Developer Community" issues, we can still thumb up/thumb down the comments. I also reported *Larry Hu \[MSFT\]*'s response on the initial issue. The popup read that it was reported for "moderation," so I don't know if anything comes of it. Don't blame me, MSFT. When the best we can do is make some noise, then noise it is.